# Random values of voltage near ADC in current loop

Tags: current, opto-isolator

I have implemented a circuit which allows to isolate a current-loop-based sensors. The schematic is as follows:

[image: current loop]

Everything seemed to work good in the breadboard. Without a MAX14626 IC, the circuit started from 2 mA. Now, I have this circuit on the PCB board. I get some voltage oscillations on the `R13` resistor when the current is in the range between 4 and 5.5 mA. In the range between 5.5 - 20 mA everything works quite good.

What are possible issues with such solution?

Comment: Where did you get the idea of this opto isolated differential amplifier?

Comment: Have you tried putting a small capacitance ~50pf from pin 1 to pin 2 on the op amp to limit the high frequency gain?

Comment: Many opamps are not stable for closed-loop-gains less than ONE.

Answer (score 4):

The circuit has oscillations because parasitic inductance and capacitance is less on the PCB, and on the breadboard the RLC pole was at a point where the circuit didn't oscillate.

It's hard to say exactly where to put the capacitance,these circuits are difficult to analyze by hand. I would first try capacitors on R11 and R12 as it's easier to create filters on the input. This would form a low pass filter so calculate the RC time constant and set it below the frequency of oscillation (and hopefully this is outside the bandwidth of your current signal).

As a side note: I didn't see anything for matching between the optocouplers in the datasheet, optocouplers can have a transfer function that varies widely even on the same part (the Ic/If ratio can vary from 63 to 125% on the ILD206) it may be advantageous for your application to use a part like the HCNR200 where the photodiodes and LED's are guaranteed to be matched if you need to back calculate what the current is through the current loop. (Or you could also calibrate each circuit)